# regex to build string till it encounters Nth match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a bit of RegEx in JavaScript to remake a URL gotten via `document.URL`. In searching I stumbled upon `var match = str.match(/([^;]*;){2}/)[0];` which builds a string to up to the second occurrence of a `;` and i need it to build up till the Nth occurrence of `/`.

While this just needs a few changes, I would also like to pass a JavaScript variable to it instead of having it be static. I'll update my answer as i do more research on JS RegEx and post a solution that works for me.

Comment: While you are searching, let me suggest using RegEx constructor rather than literal notation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: I did that after the first answer was posted so i could better understand it. Thanks for the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use snippets like this (I modified your regex to use a non-capturing group and now, we do not need to use indexing):

```js
var n = 5;
var re = new RegExp("(?:[^/]*/){" + n + "}");
var result = "Path/more/paths/here/andhere/file.php".match(re);
console.log(result);
```

NOTE: There is no need escaping `/` symbol when defining a regex pattern within a `RegExp` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer was deleted it seems, but it was a working solution so i will repost it and explain it to the best of my knowledge

`var n = 5 
var re = new RegExp('([^/]*/){' + n + '}');
var result = str.match(re)[0]`

`n` is where you would like to stop building the RegExp Object

The RegExp Object is built so that it creates a string until it reaches the nth `/`

The `result` is the running of the RegExp against the string and outputting the first result in the array

Credit to vks for the answer. I did not come up with this he did.

Comment: You owe one to vks :).

Comment: Was that his username? i had missed it when i was using his script. I'll be sure to edit my post to mention him

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're after without more explanation, but here's how I interpreted your question:

```
function getPath(url, depth) {
    var match, re, results = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= depth; i++) {
        re = new RegExp('([^/]*/){' + i + '}');
        match = url.match(re);
        if (match !== null) { results.push(match[1]); }
    }
    return results;
}
```

And using it on an example:

```
getPath('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369626/regex-to-build-string-till-it-encounters-nth-match', 5);
// returns
["http:/", "/", "stackoverflow.com/", "questions/", "29369626/"]
```